# How to change the text inside a div by hovering over other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basically I am making some concept logic for a project I am working on. It's a portfolio with boxes of images and I want to be able to change the value of a h2 to some description text based on the box that was hovered on.

Right now it's just a black box so 'square1, square2, square3...etc' will work for now. I looked up some stuff on jquery and found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ssFpH/) link from a stackoverflow answer. This does what I need but is only shifting through one piece of information instead of many in my case.

Wondering how I can achieve that via jquery. I imagine I would need to make an array with all the descriptions I need, and (this is where I am lost) somehow attach the value of array to the square and then from there change text of h2 to the array value.

Thanks for any help in advance [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/kmCQL/) what I have so far (not much just did some foundation work). Not sure if this matters but if there is no hover I want the h2 to say nothing.

HTML (makes me post code if I have jsfiddle)

```
<div class="squares">
    <div class="square1"></div>
    <div class="square2"></div>
    <div class="square3"></div>
    <div class="square4"></div>
    <div class="square5"></div>
    <h2 class="squareIdent"> </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: if ti helps this is what I am going for/was inspired by http://danielmarkiewicz.com/

Comment: why is this downvoted? Honestly I have no idea why this would be downvoted, at least provide a description why you downvoted it. This site is really something sometimes let me tell you.

Comment: If you read the down vote description, people think "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: You could use the new "data" attributes to hold your "replacement" text and then use jQuery to swap the H2 value with the div's "data" attribute (ie your new text) and then return the original on mouse exit. You will need two variables. One to store the original value, the other to store the "data" attribute.

Comment: i dont have any research effort because I have no idea where to start. I have taken many web dev classes, and what I am trying to do I simply have not done before. I am looking for a way to attach a array to the boxes, and somehow have each box be a element in the array. I don't know how to research for that, that's why I came here.

Comment: @BigChris Thanks. Didn't know about the data attribute. That makes sense and I will try that, thanks for helping and providing input.

Comment: You're starting with an empty H2 and when someone hovers over one of your "squares" the H2 is supposed to be populated with text relating to the square just hovered over. Upon the user exiting the square the H2 is supposed to be emptied?

Comment: yes basically like this: danielmarkiewicz.com

Comment: @user3624298 I understand what you are asking and that you need help, but I tend to side with those casting down votes. It sounds like you have a fundamental understanding of the problem and could have come up with some sort approach to a solution on your own (even if it did not fully work). As it is, this question is way too broad. There are many valid ways of approaching your problem. That is why there have been down votes.

Comment: @user3624298 I did not cast a down vote. Your question is simple, but I do maintain that it is too broad.

Comment: Because the problem is simple you should have been able to research and find an approach on your own.

Comment: Without knowing about the data attribute it didn't matter what I looked up. I did not think about your answer, I'm more of a programmer so I just had the mindset that these details would need to be in an array. I also need them to be in an array because I will also have a menu that will highlight each of the squares that match up with the genre you clicked on. Having the data attribute is a little more helpful.

Comment: I also wasn't necessarilly looking for a direct answer. I come to SO for programming q's and most of the time people will give amazing feedback without giving you the answer. Like for instance, explaining 'hey check out data attributes and how you might change the text of your h2 to that'. You're right though, I just wasn't thinking clearly about just hiding my details, although I feel like that is a little messier than what I would like my code to look like, it would have worked and I could have posted that and asked how I can make it cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this using data attribute to hold your description that you want your box to load in the h2 -

**Working Example -** http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/CdiHa

**Explanation**

Write your HTML in this structure -

```
<div class="squares">
    <div class="square" data-content="Alpha"></div>
    <div class="square" data-content="Beta"></div>
    <div class="square" data-content="Gamma"></div>
    <h2 class="square-data-holder"></h2>
</div>
```

Notice I have added data-content that will hold whatever text you want it to hold. We will use this to extract the same when we have to fill it in the h2.

Use this jQuery snippet to achieve the hover effect -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.square').hover(
    function() {
      $('.square-data-holder').text($(this).data('content')).fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
      $('.square-data-holder').fadeOut('slow');
   });
});
```

hover() takes two handlers to handle hover in & hover out - $( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut ), Refer - http://api.jquery.com/hover/

So on hover of any of the div's with class square, we get hold of the content of the div that was hovered using -

```
$(this).data('content')
```

And we append the same to the h2 element. On hover out, we just make h2 empty.

This should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. Understand this perfectly now '$('.square-data-holder').append($(this).data('content'));
    }, function() {
      $('.square-data-holder').empty();' makes a lot of sense. Thank you again.

Comment: @user3624298 - this is not to get the accept back on my answer, but just for learning purpose, the approach I have taken is slightly better in terms of code readability, not repeating similar kind of code like classnames,animate function etc & use of animate when its not required & can be done in a simpler way using fadeOut, fadeIn. Check the updated codepen with animate - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/CdiHa

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the example at http://danielmarkiewicz.com/ it looks like you may need to have formatted content inserted into the heading. Here is one approach to do that with HTML content inside each square.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/EZN9B/)

HTML

```
<div class="squares">
  <div class="square square1">
    <span class="heading">
      <h1>Square 1</h1>
      <h2>Details</h2>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="square square2">
    <span class="heading">
      <h1>Square 2</h1>
      <h2>Details</h2>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="square square3">
    <span class="heading">
      <h1>Square 3</h1>
      <h2>Details</h2>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="square square4">
    <span class="heading">
      <h1>Square 4</h1>
      <h2>Details</h2>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="square square5">
    <span class="heading">
      <h1>Square 5</h1>
      <h2>Details</h2>
    </span>
  </div>
  <header class="squareIdent"></header>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.heading { display: none; }  // Hide the heading content within Squares
```

JavaScript

```
$(document)
  .on('mouseover', '.square', function(e) {
    var self = $(this),
        headingContent = self.find('.heading').first().html();
    $('.squareIdent', self.closest('.squares')).html(headingContent);
  })
  .on('mouseout', '.square', function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    $('.squareIdent', self.closest('.squares')).html(null);
  })
;
```

Comment: this is definitely a better approach.

Comment: yeah i feel kind of stupid lol. Although I feel like this is not very clean code, in a perfect world having an array with all the details stored in elements would be more efficient but thanks wasn't even thinking about this.

Answer (score 0):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kmCQL/3/)

I am probablly late as Nitish already gave a good answer but here is what i have done.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="squares">
    <div class="square1" data-text="I am Square 1"></div>
    <div class="square2" data-text="I am Square 2"></div>
    <div class="square3" data-text="I am Square 3"></div>
    <div class="square4" data-text="I am Square 4"></div>
    <div class="square5" data-text="I am Square 5"></div>
    <h2 class="squareIdent"> </h2>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.square1, div.square2, div.square3, div.square4, div.square5
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 126px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    float: left;
}

div.squares
{
    margin-left: 175px;
}
.squareIdent{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(".squares > *").hover(function(){
    $(".squareIdent").text($(this).attr("data-text"));
    $(".squareIdent").stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);
}, function(){
    $(".squareIdent").stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500);
});
```

Note i have added the **Animation** as you showed in your question.