# having issues with bools in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

ok so I will explain my question, but also show you a live version to help better understand.

I have a set of images, for now they are just black squares. When you hover over the square there's a brief description of what will be there, for now it's placeholder information. I have a navigation that when you click on a genre (in this case it's just a and b for now) it only shows you the squares that are related to what you clicked. It dims opacity to 0 for the squares that dont belong. Awesome, Except it still gives me the description of a square even after it's dimmed to 0. No problem, should be able to throw a boolean and ONLY display the description if the bool is true. But this doesn't work for web programming for some reason when I try it it feels like the bool doesn't get updated.

Example:

```
if(testBool)
{
$(".square").hover(function(){
    $(".squareIdentA").text($(this).attr("data-text"));
    $(".squareIdentA").stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);
}
```

Now i think it goes without being said that I would set testbool to true when it needed to be, but when I try this it doesn't work. Kind of makes sense since this is under the (document).ready() so it only loads at start, but how else would I achieve a bool effect to only display something if bool is true, but it might be true or false at any point in the users experience.

Hard to put into words, I think I explained it correctly, but if you want a visual explanation go to (http://jdmdev.net/projects/portfolio.html#) click the welcome thing, click 'a' or 'b' on nav and then either one you pick you can hover over the disappeared squares and it still shows description. The description syntax is what I posted, so I would only want that to happen if the bool is true.

Comment: I thought of making a function, and calling the function, however there would be no way to say only if the bool was true call the function, that puts me in same situation I'm currently in. I know there must be some way to do this, thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Your logic is wrong – what you _have_ done, is make binding the event handler to the element dependent on your boolean value; what you actually _want_ to do is call the animation only when the value is true. So your check for `testBool` should be inside your hover handler function. (You could do it another way, and _remove_ the hover handler when it’s not applicable any more as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this by adding a specific class to all the selected genre & adding another class to the rest of the ones your made faded out. Then in your hover function you can keep a check to see if the faded class is not there, only then show the description.

**WORKING DEMO - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/CdiHa**

Something like this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.square').hover(
    function() {
      if($(this).hasClass('in-active')) {
        return false;
      }
      $('.square-data-holder').text($(this).data('content')).fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
      $('.square-data-holder').fadeOut('slow');

    });

    $('#selectGenre').change(function(){
       var genre = $(this).val();
       $('.square').removeClass('active').addClass('in-active');
       $('.genre-' + genre).removeClass('in-active').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: ah okay. that makes sense now. Little different than programming, something to get used to, but thanks very much.

Comment: you're welcome. are you the same guy who asked this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877813/how-to-change-the-text-inside-a-div-by-hovering-over-other-elements/ or for some reason everyone is working with black boxes & this project :)